# Spark Cassandra connector with Java for read

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Requirement :-
I have persisted data in cassandra and on hourly basis i need to calculate some score based on updates happening to records.I see data coming correctly by using the show() method on dataset

Below code to read data :-

```
Dataset<DealFeedSchema> dealFeedSchemaDataset = session.read()
     .format(Constants.SPARK_CASSANDRA_SOURCE_PATH)
     .option(Constants.KEY_SPACE, Constants.CASSANDRA_KEY_SPACE)
     .option(Constants.TABLE, Constants.CASSANDRA_DEAL_TABLE_SPACE)
     .option(Constants.DATE_FORMAT, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
     .schema(DealFeedSchema.getDealFeedSchema())
     .load()
     .as(Encoders.bean(DealFeedSchema.class));
dealFeedSchemaDataset.show();
```

output of show is below:

```
+-------+----------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------------------+---------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|deal_id| deal_name|deal_category|           deal_tags|growth_tags|deal_tag_ids|deal_price|deal_discount_percentage|deal_group_size|deal_active|    deal_start_time|        deal_expiry|product_id|product_name|product_description|product_category|product_category_id|product_price|hero_image|      product_images| video_url|video_thumbnail_image_url|deal_like_count|deal_share_count|deal_view_count|deal_buy_count|weighted_score|boost|
+-------+----------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------------------+---------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|      4|7h12349961|          mqw|[under999, under3...|         []|          []|    4969.0|                    null|       95166551|          1|2020-07-08 14:48:57|2020-07-18 14:48:57|4725457233|  kao62ggnm7|         32h64e356z|      jnnh29zr1f|               null|       6651.0|86kk7s34yr|[dSt4P79, i4WXOHb...|d6tag27924|               4j1l36lp17|           null|            null|           null|          null|          null| null|
```

So here's weired thing that happens when i use map/foreach on **dealFeedSchemaDataset** the data seems not correct i get the column value of **deal_start_time** as current system time something like below, not sure how this gets changed.

even below line gives same issue:

```
dealFeedSchemaDataset.select(
      functions.col("deal_start_time")).as(Encoders.bean(DateTime.class))
.collectAsList().forEach(schema -> System.out.println(schema));
```

```
2020-07-10T20:21:47.895+05:30
```

can someone help me with what am i doing wrong?

Comment: why you need to do `as` again if you already did it when loading the data. Also, the issue could come from the use of the incorrect type in `.as` inside `.select` -> the field is most probably has `timestamp` type, and you need to use `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.sql.Date` for it...

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt yes you are right i was doing trial and error on the code. java.sql.timestamp is the answer i was looking for. i used joda timestamp but that was not working. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
java.sql.Timestamp
```

This for using formats which contains time part in it

```
java.sql.Date
```

This for just the dates